# Windows Phone 8.1 App on App Store Issue

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-store

I have created windows phone 8.1 application, I have created WCF service and called this WCF Service with my PC IP in this app, I have not hosted WCF service publicly on AZURE or etc, So If I upload this app on Windows Phone store, then will it run on any device and on any network?
This is my first app, so I don't know how to deal with? So, please guide me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using PC IP is not recommended.

First check, if you can even call you WCF outside your organization. Moreover your PC IP could change (dynamic IP). It even depends on your ISP, on which you don't have any control.

Best thing is to host it somewhere.

Comment: Saqib Vaid, ok thank you for your response, I am not able to call WCF service outside my organization, and on any other network except my PC network. Any suggestions?

Comment: @NiteshKothari I guess you have to speak to your network team in your org to get this sorted out. We had a similar case in my company were had to expose an internal IP to some client. It was done by our IT Network & Security teams. (By pass firewalls etc)

Comment: Saqib, ok, can you do me one favor? When I install app on device, can I change my project URL to "localhost" instead of PC IP? I think that is the point. Will app run with "localhost" URL?

Comment: It will not work, once the app is installed it will look for the WCF on the same device. Localhost means the IP of the device or PC you are on.

Comment: Saqib, ok thanks!!So, everything I need to do is with Public IP and hosting.

Comment: Exactly ! You r welcome. Will b glad if you can mark it as answer.